# flutter how to convert a list in a map

Tags: flutter, api, calendar

please can someone help me i need to convert this model:

```
import 'dart:convert';


class EventsModel {
  final String descricaoJob;
  final String dataDoJob;
  final String horarioInicialDoJob;
  final String horarioFinalDoJob;
  EventsModel({
    required this.descricaoJob,
    required this.dataDoJob,
    required this.horarioInicialDoJob,
    required this.horarioFinalDoJob,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'descricaoJob': descricaoJob,
      'dataDoJob': dataDoJob,
      'horarioInicialDoJob': horarioInicialDoJob,
      'horarioFinalDoJob': horarioFinalDoJob,
    };
  }

  factory EventsModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return EventsModel(
      descricaoJob: map['descricao'],
      dataDoJob: map['data_acao'],
      horarioInicialDoJob: map['hora_inicial_acao'],
      horarioFinalDoJob: map['hora_final_acao'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory EventsModel.fromJson(String source) => EventsModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

on a map where the key is the job date field and the value is the job description field, looking something like this:

```
final events <Map<DateTime, List>> = {
      dataDoJob: descricaoDoJob,
      dataDoJob: descricaoDoJob,
    }
```

this is my json it is a little big but the fields i need to get i marked with this

```
[
    {
        "codigo_cupom": null,
        "data_acao": "2021-07-11", //THIS
        "deleted_at": null,
        "descricao": "Teste de Job 1", //THIS
        "hashtags": null,
        "hora_final_acao": "12:00:00", //THIS
        "hora_inicial_acao": "08:00:00", //THIS
        "job": {
            "canal_entrada": "Telefone",
            "cliente": {
                "cidade": "Portland",
                "cliente_id": 1,
                "cnpj": "12.345.678/0001-12",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "descricao": "Nike",
                "endereco": "1 Nike Drive",
                "estado": "SP",
                "last_modified_by": null,
                "last_time": "2021-07-11T19:13:54+00:00",
                "login_instagram": "nike",
                "nome": "Nike",
                "nota_fiscal": null,
                "numero_seguidores_instagram": null,
                "observacoes": null,
                "razao_social": "Nike Inc",
                "telefone_comercial": "(11) 1111-1111",
                "website": "https://nike.com"
            },
            "cliente_id": 1,
            "data_inicio": "2021-07-11",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "descricao": "Teste de Job",
            "influenciador": {
                "altura": null,
                "avatar": null,
                "busto_cms": null,
                "calcinha_sunga_tamanho": null,
                "casting_mailing": null,
                "cidade": null,
                "cidade_nascimento": null,
                "cintura_cms": null,
                "cnpj": null,
                "cor_cabelo": null,
                "cor_olhos": null,
                "cpf": null,
                "dados_bancarios_agencia": null,
                "dados_bancarios_banco": null,
                "dados_bancarios_conta": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pf_chave_pix": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pf_cpf": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pf_nome": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_agencia": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_banco": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_chave_pix": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_conta": null,
                "data_nascimento": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "email": "ronaldinho@gaucho.com",
                "email_responsavel_mailing": null,
                "endereco": null,
                "estado": null,
                "estado_civil": null,
                "estado_nascimento": null,
                "etnia": null,
                "filhos": null,
                "formacao": null,
                "frase_destaque": "Estão deixando a gente sonhar",
                "influenciador_id": 20,
                "last_modified_by": null,
                "last_time": "2021-07-11T19:13:54+00:00",
                "login_instagram": "ronaldinho",
                "login_twitter": null,
                "manequim_baixo": null,
                "manequim_cima": null,
                "marca_dedicada": null,
                "nome": "Ronaldo",
                "nome_artistico": "Ronaldinho Gaúcho",
                "nome_responsavel_mailing": null,
                "numero_sapato": null,
                "numero_seguidores_instagram": 54396462,
                "numero_soutien": null,
                "percentual_comissao": null,
                "periodo_dedicado": null,
                "peso": null,
                "pessoa_id": 20,
                "pets": null,
                "quadril_cms": null,
                "razao_social": null,
                "responsavel": 2,
                "responsavel_id": 2,
                "rg": null,
                "sexo": "M",
                "sobrenome": "de Assis Moreira",
                "telefone": "(11) 99999-9999",
                "telefone_responsavel_mailing": null,
                "texto": null,
                "tipo_cabelo": null,
                "token_senha": null,
                "url": null,
                "url_facebook": null,
                "url_media_kit": null,
                "url_youtube": null,
                "valor_pacote_fotos": 0.00,
                "valor_post": 0.00,
                "valor_post_facebook": 0.00,
                "valor_post_stories": 0.00,
                "valor_presenca": 0.00,
                "valor_shooting": 0.00,
                "valor_stories": 0.00,
                "valor_take_over": 0.00,
                "valor_video": 0.00,
                "valor_youtube": 0.00
            },
            "influenciador_id": 20,
            "job_id": 1,
            "last_modified_by": null,
            "last_time": "2021-07-11T19:13:54+00:00",
            "nota_fiscal": false,
            "observacoes": "",
            "participacao": 100,
            "quantidade_posts": 1,
            "quantidade_presencas": 1,
            "quantidade_stories": 1,
            "status": "nao_iniciado",
            "tipo_demanda": "Espontâneo",
            "valor": 1000.00
        },
        "job_acao_id": 1,
        "job_id": 1,
        "last_modified_by": null,
        "last_time": "2021-07-11T19:13:54+00:00",
        "link_produto": null,
        "periodo": null,
        "status": "nao_iniciada",
        "tipo_acao": "Post",
        "titulo": "Teste de Job 1",
        "valor": 1000.00
    },
    {
        "codigo_cupom": null,
        "data_acao": "2021-10-29",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque gravida quam ut est posuere eleifend. In ac augue semper, sollicitudin nisl id, auctor lacus. Praesent faucibus eros condimentum elementum molestie. Fusce id eros enim. Cras sollicitudin lectus eu purus aliquam luctus.\n\nMaecenas tristique ultrices sem, quis commodo mauris egestas quis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc maximus nisi a libero egestas, convallis aliquam urna vulputate. Vestibulum eget auctor ante, ornare mollis massa.",
        "hashtags": "#ParquedoPovo #Run21 #MarcaX",
        "hora_final_acao": "17:00:00",
        "hora_inicial_acao": "15:00:00",
        "job": {
            "canal_entrada": null,
            "cliente": {
                "cidade": "Portland",
                "cliente_id": 1,
                "cnpj": "12.345.678/0001-12",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "descricao": "Nike",
                "endereco": "1 Nike Drive",
                "estado": "SP",
                "last_modified_by": null,
                "last_time": "2021-07-11T19:13:54+00:00",
                "login_instagram": "nike",
                "nome": "Nike",
                "nota_fiscal": null,
                "numero_seguidores_instagram": null,
                "observacoes": null,
                "razao_social": "Nike Inc",
                "telefone_comercial": "(11) 1111-1111",
                "website": "https://nike.com"
            },
            "cliente_id": 1,
            "data_inicio": null,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "descricao": "Fazer reels no parque do povo, usar roupas da marca com close no tênis.",
            "influenciador": {
                "altura": null,
                "avatar": null,
                "busto_cms": null,
                "calcinha_sunga_tamanho": null,
                "casting_mailing": null,
                "cidade": null,
                "cidade_nascimento": null,
                "cintura_cms": null,
                "cnpj": null,
                "cor_cabelo": null,
                "cor_olhos": null,
                "cpf": null,
                "dados_bancarios_agencia": null,
                "dados_bancarios_banco": null,
                "dados_bancarios_conta": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pf_chave_pix": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pf_cpf": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pf_nome": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_agencia": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_banco": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_chave_pix": null,
                "dados_bancarios_pj_conta": null,
                "data_nascimento": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "email": "ronaldinho@gaucho.com",
                "email_responsavel_mailing": null,
                "endereco": null,
                "estado": null,
                "estado_civil": null,
                "estado_nascimento": null,
                "etnia": null,
                "filhos": null,
                "formacao": null,
                "frase_destaque": "Estão deixando a gente sonhar",
                "influenciador_id": 20,
                "last_modified_by": null,
                "last_time": "2021-07-11T19:13:54+00:00",
                "login_instagram": "ronaldinho",
                "login_twitter": null,
                "manequim_baixo": null,
                "manequim_cima": null,
                "marca_dedicada": null,
                "nome": "Ronaldo",
                "nome_artistico": "Ronaldinho Gaúcho",
                "nome_responsavel_mailing": null,
                "numero_sapato": null,
                "numero_seguidores_instagram": 54396462,
                "numero_soutien": null,
                "percentual_comissao": null,
                "periodo_dedicado": null,
                "peso": null,
                "pessoa_id": 20,
                "pets": null,
                "quadril_cms": null,
                "razao_social": null,
                "responsavel": 2,
                "responsavel_id": 2,
                "rg": null,
                "sexo": "M",
                "sobrenome": "de Assis Moreira",
                "telefone": "(11) 99999-9999",
                "telefone_responsavel_mailing": null,
                "texto": null,
                "tipo_cabelo": null,
                "token_senha": null,
                "url": null,
                "url_facebook": null,
                "url_media_kit": null,
                "url_youtube": null,
                "valor_pacote_fotos": 0.00,
                "valor_post": 0.00,
                "valor_post_facebook": 0.00,
                "valor_post_stories": 0.00,
                "valor_presenca": 0.00,
                "valor_shooting": 0.00,
                "valor_stories": 0.00,
                "valor_take_over": 0.00,
                "valor_video": 0.00,
                "valor_youtube": 0.00
            },
            "influenciador_id": 20,
            "job_id": 8,
            "last_modified_by": 16,
            "last_time": "2021-10-19T20:30:49+00:00",
            "nota_fiscal": false,
            "observacoes": null,
            "participacao": 100,
            "quantidade_posts": null,
            "quantidade_presencas": null,
            "quantidade_stories": null,
            "status": "nao_iniciado",
            "tipo_demanda": null,
            "valor": 3000.00
        },
        "job_acao_id": 15,
        "job_id": 8,
        "last_modified_by": 16,
        "last_time": "2021-10-19T20:30:49+00:00",
        "link_produto": null,
        "periodo": "Tarde",
        "status": "nao_iniciada",
        "tipo_acao": "Reels",
        "titulo": "Parque do povo",
        "valor": 3000.00
    }
]
```

this is my method that is accessing the api and getting the data, I need to convert them to <Map<DateTime, List>> to be able to use it in the table calendar, if someone can help me I'm really grateful

```
 @override
  Future<List<EventsModel>> getEvents() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final int? id = sharedPreferences.getInt("idInfluencer");
    final String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token") ?? "";

    final Response result = await _restClient.get<List<EventsModel>>(
        "/job_acoes?influenciador_id=${id.toString()}",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        }, decoder: (data) {
      if (data != null) {
        return data.map<EventsModel>((event)=> EventsModel.fromMap(event)).toList();
      }
      return <EventsModel>[];
    });
    if (result.hasError) {
      print(result.statusCode);
      throw "Erro ao buscar dados";
    }

    print(result.body);

    return result.body;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a `Map<DateTime, List<String>>` or a `Map<DateTime, String>` ? What do you want to do with the times that you have marked as //this? Add them to the date? How do you want to handle the fact that each event has a start and end date/time? What's the actual requirement of where you are sending the map of dates to something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you have a method that fetches a list of `EventsModel` from an API and you want to turn it into a map of type `Map<DateTime, List<String>>`? If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
Map<DateTime, List<String>> modelsToMap(List<EventsModel> models) {
  Map<DateTime, List<String>> map = {};
  for (model in models) {
    DateTime time = DateTime.parse(model.dataDoJob);
    if (map.containsKey(time)) {
      map[time].add(model.descricaoDoJob);
    } else {
      map[time] = [model.descricaoDoJob];
    }
  }

  return map;
}
```

Comment: `putIfAbsent` would be cleaner. This will throw a null pointer when you try to `add` to a null list.

Comment: sorry for my english, i am using the translator. Thank you very much for the answer, but for me the method did not work. I've been trying to add events to the table calendar for days from an api. The api returns a list of my model, and the table calendar receives a map with the key being of type dateTime and the value being a string, but I'm not able to do this conversion